# Can you run a Powershell script through WSUS?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-update

I have a powershell script that can collect software info, bios version, etc. when it is run on a single machine. Is there a way that I can automate this using WSUS so that it runs against all my machines that are connected to this WSUS server?

Comment: If you can export the machines into a list, you can run the script against that list.

Comment: Why don't you use the group policy to run the script?

Answer (score 0):

You should use GPO for run any startup scripts:

http://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/